# AWS architecture for geo location app?

Tags: ios, node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am designing the architecture for a new geo location app I am building. Instead of going with some older technologies I am familiar with I plan on building out the  app and website using something new. I've read tons of documentation but it's still a bit confusing to me.

Here is my architectural design so far:

- iPhone and Andriod app written in react-native
- Node JS servers in AWS behind an ELB
- AWS RDS postgresql database
- S3 bucket

I plan on having the mobile app communicate to the ELB in AWS which will have an auto scale group of single cpu node js servers behind it. The node js servers will connect to the RDS postgresql db which will contain user information and other data. I will use the CDN enabled S3 bucket to serve static content and images.

It all sounds good in theory but has anyone ever tried this in practice? Are there other parts of the architecture I'm missing ?

Comment: Have you considered using node.js functions in AWS Lambda for handling short-lived requests, rather than (or in addition to) using Amazon EC2 instances?

Comment: I'm going to use Lamba for the image resizing process.

Comment: For image resizing, you could also use services like [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) and [Imgix](http://imgix.com/). Basically, it's Resizing as a Service.